# Remix fail to render after i put hour in component

Tags: remix, remix.run

[white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me3YN.png)

[component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jzcj.png)

time is: '2022-08-31T08:25:00.000Z'

Why remix entry client is failing only when  i put datetime.hour or datetime.minute???

Update:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

type CommonProps = {
  time: String;
};

type Props = CommonProps;

export const MlTimeComponentNew: React.FC<Props> = ({ time }) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const parsed = DateTime.fromISO(time);

  return (
    <div className="mb-4 flex justify-center" key={12345}>
      <div className="ml-3 text-2xl">
        {parsed.hour}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**LAST UPDATE**:
Problem was in component actually:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

type CommonProps = {
  time: String;
};

type Props = CommonProps;

export const MlTimeComponentNew: React.FC<Props> = ({ time }) => {
   const parsed2 = DateTime.fromISO(time, {zone: 'utc'});
  const [hour, setHour] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHour(parsed2.hour);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mb-4 flex justify-center" key={12345}>
      <div className="ml-3 text-2xl">
        {hour}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I still don't understand why remix is creating problem with first implementation

Comment: Please post he code and error as text, not an image.

Comment: i have updated post, now you can see the code :) One more addition, if i put parsed.day everything is working as expected

Comment: export const MlTimeComponentNew = ({ time }) => { .... Same result :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue in the first code snippet from the question. I even tried the provided code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-luxon-parsed-hour?file=app%2Froutes%2F_index.tsx), and it is working fine there as well. The provided error might be coming from something else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your updated example works because it defines time as UTC. UTC is for server and client the same, so there is no hydration error.

Otherwise server and client might use different time zones, leading to hydration errors since server and client trees are not identical.

I'm guessing because I don't know what `luxon` does.